# Как отменить действие return false?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день, прошу помощи и совета.

Есть список вида

```
<li><a href="index.php?id=1">Текст1</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=2">Текст2</a></li>
```

В процессе работы текст ссылки (Текст1) может редактироваться с помощью jquery, в этот момент переход по второй ссылке (Текст2) блокирован с помощью return false:

```
$("#category li").click(function(){ 
   return false;
});
```

Подскажите, можно ли как-то отменить действие return false с помощью jquery и вернуть работоспособность ссылки после завершения редактирования без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
$("#category li").on('click', function(){ 
   return false;
});

$("#category li").off('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать завести переменную, которая будет говорить, что сейчас происходит редактирование и переход запрещён. В этот момент она будет false. Тогда код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var blocker = false;

//Где-то, где происходит редактирование blocker надо сделать равной true
//Тогда в коде ниже не буде срабатывать переход по ссылке

$("#category li").click(function(){
    if (blocker) {
        return false;
    }
});
```